# Looping through a list/dictionary django template

Tags: python, django

```
my view.
teamname_list = team.objects.values('teamName')

in my template template html
{{teamname_list}}

outputs:
[{'teamName': "['Paul', 'John']"}]
---------------------------------------------------
alternatively values instead of values_list
view
teamname_list = team.objects.values('teamName')
in template
{{teamname_list}}
output:
[("['Paul', 'John']",)]
```

Is there any way to loop through teamname_list to get the characters individually so on the html page it shows as just Paul and John, treated as their own string or even producing a list so looping through them and adding them to an unordered list i.e.

```
* paul
* john
```

Been trying for a while now couple of hours and can't seem to get anything to work, tried every possible solution except for filters because I seem to be having a problem with using them. Any other solutions?

Comment: What is the field type of teamName in your model class?

Comment: Could you add the models as well.

Comment: You need to show your whole view. You're doing something very odd to have a single string containing your two values, inside a tuple, inside a list.

Comment: Players are added to a list, by doing team.players so that explains the string will be the team name that players are in.. team: player1,player2,player3... so by me adding team.players to the list I think it may just be adding the players to the list, then making the teamname a string?

Comment: Down vote when you asked this question before you were asked to provide additional information. You haven't done that but asked virtually the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for) in your django template. For example:

```
<ul>
  {% for teamname in teamname_list %}
    <li>{{ teamname }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

EDIT: I didn't realize your list actually only has one value. Try doing this for starters:

```
teamname_list = team.objects.all()
```

Comment: No that will print out : *("[Paul', 'John']",) where star is a bullet point

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize your list had one value: `"['Paul', 'John']"`. I think you may be accessing it wrong in the view, see my edit.

Comment: all() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Hmm, did you do just `teamname_list = team.objects.all()`? Or did you try something like `teamname_list = team.objects.all('teamName')`?

Comment: yes i do team.objects.all('teamName') because that is where the column where my lists are stored with the difference team names.

Comment: oh, `all` takes no args. try what i suggested

Comment: all returns the complete wrong attributes, it doesn't return anything from teamname

Comment: after that, it looks like you're retrieving a dict. so once you get `teamname_list` back from using `team.objects.all()` you should be able to do:
`teamname_list['teamName']` to get an actual list.

Comment: makes sense, don't think that's the right syntax though teamname_list['teamName'] so trying to look it up in docs

Comment: I would call it `teamname_dict` instead, and using `['keyName']` is one way to access a dictionary value. There is also: `teamname_dict.get('teamName','Default value')` where `'Default value'` can be whatever you want; e.g. your own list, dict, string, int, etc... whatever you want to return if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Comment: get can't be called because too many values to unpack as well as tname['key'] also failing with no exc message

Answer (score 0):

```
teamname_list = team.objects.values_list('teamName', flat=True)
```

This will return list of names. Use one for loop in template and display names.

```
<ul>
  {% for teamname in teamname_list %}
    <li>*{{ teamname }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: this will return a list ( bullet point ) for each letter in the team name... so, anoop = * a * n * o * o * p and not *anoop

Comment: @Paul9, share your model and one sample query response

Answer (score 0):

```
teamname_list = team.objects.all()
```

HTML code

```
<ul>
  {% for name in teamname_list %}
    <li>{{ name.teamName }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Please share your model for more clarification